# Vim and key mapping

Tags: vim

I would like to enable or disable mouse support in vim with only one key (in my case <kbd>F7</kbd>). It should work in command mode insert mode. I have this in my .virmrc:

```
  set mouse=
  nnoremap <F7>       :set mouse=a <CR>
  inoremap <F7> <C-o> :set mouse=a  <CR>
```

but this does not work. I also want to switch `cursorline` on and off in both modes. For this I have this in my .vimrc

```
set nocursorline
nnoremap <F2>      :set cursorline!<CR>
inoremap <F2> <C-o>:set cursorline!<CR>
```

Cursorline works well, mouse support does not. Why?

Comment: sorry, i mean: "edit mode" = insert mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` modifier in your cursorline example is why it is working. That tells Vim to toggle or invert the current value. It only works for boolean (true/false) settings.

From `:help :set`:

> `:se[t] {option}!`   or
>   `:se[t] inv{option}`      Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}

In your `mouse` case, you'll need something a little more intelligent.

```
function ToggleMouse()
    if &mouse == 'a'
        set mouse=
        echo 'Mouse mode OFF'
    else
        set mouse=a
        echo 'Mouse mode ON'
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <F7> :call ToggleMouse()<CR>
inoremap <F7> <C-o>:call ToggleMouse()<CR>
```